# DateTime check if it is in UTC format

Tags: c#, date, datetime, formatting

I have a question about date time format.
I have a string, that represents my datetime:
"2014-08-01T10:12:11.0Z". Actually, as I understand, it is a datetime in utc format, because 'Z' shows me offset from UTC.

And then I try to perform

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2014-08-01T10:12:11.0Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out value_);
```

(where value_ is just my newly created DateTime object) just to check if my string represents UTC time. This expression gives me 'false'.

So, I wonder, what format should I pass instead of "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" or should I change something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.0` at the end of that string is tenths of seconds, so you need to add a parse character for it: `F`.

Also, the parse character for Z is `K`, not `Z`.

So to parse that string you will need to do this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2014-08-01T10:12:11.0Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out value);
```

Also note that if you want time zone information in the string to be parsed (i.e. if it wasn't a UTC time), it would look like this with the `Z` replaced by the timezone offset, +ve or -ve:

```
"2014-08-01T10:12:11.0-07:00" // Note time zone offset at the end.
```

Comment: It is a very good idea to devise date/time logic to treat the value *"purely* as "an 'opaque' thing,"  Don't test or make any assumptions about the underlying numeric-or-otherwise value. If you want 'Zulu time," ask for the value to be converted to "time-zone zero," and trust that it will be. If you want "the local time 'here,'" (or anywhere ...), explicitly ask for that.